# How to check if a folder is open in Windows/Macintosh and possibly close it?

Tags: python

I am working in python and sometimes with `os.rename()` I run into the problem that if the file or folder to rename is open in the windows system I get a `PermissionError: [WinError 5]` error.
So if I close the folder and rerun the script, everything works.

In any case I am working on Windows, but I think it is good practice that I take into account that it could also be run on Machintosh.

I don't know what the best practice is for this, but please have a little patience, I'm still learning python and really don't know how to ask the question any better than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To echo [Prune's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67237237/12975140), figuring out where it's in use and closing it sounds difficult, and probably not a great idea anyway. Imagine if it's not available because some other program is currently saving to one of the files — you could end up with corrupted data.

That said, you could make your Python script smart enough to notice there's a permission error, then pause and let you know so that you could try and close things on your own before telling it to try again and continue.

```py
import os

def try_to_rename(src, dst):
    while True:
        try:
            os.rename(src, dst)
            break
        except PermissionError:
            input(f"Unable to rename {src} to {dst}. If one or both "
                   "files/folders are open, please close them. Press Enter to "
                   "continue.")
```

P.S. It makes little difference for this simple example, but for working extensively with paths and files, I'd recommend [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) over `os`. It can really make things a lot more [convenient and readable](https://treyhunner.com/2018/12/why-you-should-be-using-pathlib/).

Answer (score 2):

In general, no.  This is a violation of system security: another entity (user, session, process, etc.) is using the resource (file or folder), in a way that requires exclusive rights (typically update / modify rights).  If you steal the resource, how is that other entity supposed to react or adapt to the change?

This is why an OS *has* these privileges and locks: to manage system resources.  Since you already have user control over the resource, you are supposed to use *that* authority to release the file lock -- not cracking the security from outside.

However, as the controlling user, you *do* likely have rights to view your own sessions and jobs, to inquire which one owns the resource, and then terminate the job or otherwise force it to release the resource.

In that fashion, it is possible to steal the resource from the other process.  If you want to do that, you need to educate yourself on your OS's capabilities and rights.  The most useful ones will be available through Python's `os` package.  Enjoy the learning.

Comment: This gives me a way to think that what I am doing is perhaps wrong, I will have to investigate. In any case, I don't understand why every time I ask a question here, it is evaluated negatively. I really don't know how to improve my issues, it seems that something is wrong with them, but I have pointed out that I am a "Beginner".

Comment: If you have trouble writing good questions, then repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  If that doesn't help, then ask a *specific* question -- with a link to the post with which you want help -- on the Meta site, which is the proper place.